# how to give full grant permission to rds admin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

how to give full grant permission to rds SQLserver admin

I have tried to create folder in integration service catlog but it ask for permission

Answer (score 0):

Getting whole privileges is something that aws does not give as RDS is managed service. We also had issue with grants & aws support said that, RDS being managed service, for security reason all permissions are not granted to user.
Following permissions can be granted; go through [guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/duplicate-master-user-mysql/).

These permissions are not granted -  CREATE TABLESPACE, FILE, SHUTDOWN, and SUPER